I cant reproject a mosaicked image properly in Google Earth Engine. What do I do?
I'm trying to reproduce the same projection/coordinates in the .median() image as in the .first() image. However, when reprojecting, all these values are lost. Trying to use .reproject() does not make dimensions reappear. I have also attempted to cast .toInt16() on the median image to achieve a similar data type as the first image. What am I doing wrong here? Is there some logic I am missing?
The goal here is to eventually use .medianImage.geometry() to use the image's geometry in a reduceRegion function. I have provided my problematic code below. I initially just tried to use all bands, however I was receiving an error "Image.projection: The bands of the specified image contain different projections. Use Image.select to pick a single band." so I decided to select the most important bands in the first image and resample them to the same size before using that images projection to reproject the median image.
var sentinel = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED").filter(ee.Filter.date('2021-08-01','2021-10-01'))
.filterBounds(aoi);

var firstImage = sentinel.first().select(['B5' , 'B8', 'B11' , 'B12']);

var firstImageProjection = firstImage.select('B5').projection();

firstImage = firstImage.select('B8').reproject(firstImageProjection).addBands(firstImage.select(['B5', 'B11' , 'B12']));

firstImageProjection = firstImage.projection();

print('Is the first image unbounded: ' , firstImage.geometry().isUnbounded());

print('First Image Info: ', firstImage.getInfo());

var medianImage = sentinel.select(['B5' , 'B8', 'B11' , 'B12']).median().reproject(firstImageProjection);
print('Median Image Info', medianImage.getInfo());

print('Is the new reprojected image unbounded: ' , medianImage.geometry().isUnbounded()); 

